# Upload package using Twine using Github Action

Tags: github, twine

I am uploading a package to GCP using Github action but when I tried to execute the command using my laptop (Mac) works properly but in the Github action throw the error

twine upload  --repository-url https://gcp-artifactory/project/ -u _json_key -p "CREDENTIALS" ./target/wheels/file.whl

```
                    [-s] [--sign-with SIGN_WITH] [-i IDENTITY] [-u USERNAME]
                    [-p PASSWORD] [--non-interactive] [-c COMMENT]
                    [--config-file CONFIG_FILE] [--skip-existing]
                    [--cert path] [--client-cert path] [--verbose]
                    [--disable-progress-bar]
                    dist [dist ...]
twine upload: error: the following arguments are required: dist
```

If the folder is the same, why do I have this issue? Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it?